# Сайт периодически подвисает на 3 секунды

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Сайт на связке *Nginx + FPM + MySQL*. Дело не в БД, уже провел логирование, и исправил недочеты через тюнер.

Каждые минут 5-10 при заходе на любую страницу сайта он подвисает примерно на 3 секунды (спиннер во вкладке и белый фон). После этого подвисания все летает как и должно.

> Note: До этого был *Apache 2* и была та же проблема. После полной переустановки *Ubuntu* проблема осталась.

В чем может быть дело? Как отследить и как исправить?

Upd: Такое ощущение, что браузер сбрасывает кэш и сайт начинает грузиться с нуля, как при первом посещении.

Comment: Открыть мониторинг сети в браузере, профилировщик, помониторить, попрофилировать

Comment: @andreymal спс, монитор сети в браузере решил проблему